# Exibir valor (decimal) sem arredondar

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Olá, utilizando banco de dados *mysql*, com *asp.net mvc c#*, tenho no banco de dados o seguinte valor (do tipo decimal):

**48.205864**

Portanto, quando simplesmente faço um `select`, e trago ele para a tela, é exibido dessa maneira:

**48,21**

O que eu preciso fazer para q o valor não seja arredondado no C#, e exibido corretamente igual está no banco de dados?

**extra:**
o `select`, estou utilizando o *ef*, conforme abaixo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.ipca.ToList().OrderBy(i => i.data));
        }
```

No meu model:

```
public decimal valor { get; set; }
```

Comment: Como esta configurado o seu decimal no banco, exemplo `decimal(18,2)`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic para esses dados, no banco de dados esta configurado como decimal(15,6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Após muita pesquisa, encontrei o artigo (conforme o link abaixo) que especifica e exemplifica bem a minha necessidade. O que tive que fazer foi adicionar a annotation na propriedade correspondente o valor, no meu `model`:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0,0.000000}")]`
public decimal valor { get; set; }
```

Utilizando a máscara o qual necessito, consegui imprimir na tela o valor correto de: **48.205864**

O link original para o artigo: https://goo.gl/PpOZVo
Para não correr o risco do link ficar desutilizado algum dia, segue abaixo as explicações, a qual dou crédito ao autor do link informado.

**Definindo o máximo permitido de casas decimais**
Para formatar um número com no máximo duas casas decimais, use o formato de string {0:0.##} como demonstrado no exemplo a seguir:

```
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.583); // "123.58"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.586); // "123.59"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.58);  // "123.58"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.5);   // "123.5"
string.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);   // "123"
```

**Definindo um tamanho fixo de casas decimais**
Este é similar ao exemplo acima, mas em vez de hashes (‘#’) na string de formatação, vamos usar zeros (‘0’) como a seguir:

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.583); // "123.58"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.586); // "123.59"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.58);  // "123.58"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.5);   // "123.50"
string.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);   // "123.00"
```

**O separador de milhar**
Para formatar decimal usando o separador de milhar, use a string de formatação {0:0,0} como demonstrado no exemplo a seguir:

```
string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", 1234256.583); // "1,234,256.58"
string.Format("{0:0,0}", 1234256.583);    // "1,234,257"
```

**Definindo um número fixo de dígitos antes dos decimais**
Para definir um número mínimo de tres dígitos antes dos decimais, use a string de formatação {0:000.#}.

```
string.Format("{0:00.000}", 1.2345);    // "01.235"
string.Format("{0:000.000}", 12.345);   // "012.345"
string.Format("{0:0000.000}", 123.456); // "0123.456"
```

**Alinhamento**
Para especificar o alinhamento ao metodo de formatação, deve-se escrever seu formato como a seguir. Note que foi usado virgula (‘,’) para especificar o número de caracteres usados para o alinhamento.
{0,[no. de caracteres]} e se quiser encher com zeros {0,[no. de caracteres]:00.00}

```
string.Format("{0,7:##.00}", 2.356);  // "   2.36"
string.Format("{0,-7:##.00}", 2.356); // "2.36   "
string.Format("{0,7:00.00}", 2.356);  // "  02.36"
string.Format("{0,-7:00.00}", 2.356); // "02.36  "
```

**Números positivos, negativos e zero**
Você pode incluir diferentes formatos para números positivos, negativos e zero usando o ponto e virgula (‘;’).
Format string:

```
//{0:[positive];[negative];[zero]}
string.Format("{0:000.000;(000.000);zero}", 23.43);  // "023.430"
string.Format("{0:000.000;(000.000);zero}", -23.43); // "(023.430)"
string.Format("{0:000.000;(000.000);zero}", 0.0);    // "zero"
```

**Alguns formatos pré-definidos**

```
string.Format("{0:C}", 1532.236);  // "£1,532.24"
string.Format("{0:C}", -1532.236); // "-£1,532.24"
string.Format("{0:E}", 1532.236);  // "1.532236E+003"
string.Format("{0:E}", -1532.236); // "-1.532236E+003"
string.Format("{0:F}", 1532.24);   // "1532.24"
string.Format("{0:F}", -1532.24);  // "-1532.24"
string.Format("{0:G}", 1532.236);  // "1532.236"
string.Format("{0:G}", -1532.236); // "-1532.236"
string.Format("{0:N}", 1532.236);  // "1,532.24"
string.Format("{0:N}", -1532.236); // "-1,532.24"
string.Format("{0:P}", 0.1532);    // "15.32 %"
string.Format("{0:P}", -0.1532);   // "-15.32 %"
string.Format("{0:R}", 1532.236);  // "1532.236"
string.Format("{0:R}", -1532.236); // "-1532.236"
```

Comment: Desculpa, @EricoSouza, mas, isso não responde o contexto geral da sua pergunta que tem um `ORM` (**extra**) entre tudo isso. Isso que você explicou está correto, mas, para que o ORM consiga utiliza essa configuração, ele precisa saber da configuração.

Comment: Bem lembrado @VirgilioNovic, vou atualizar a resposta.